# Question on SNORT Rule

Tags: snort

I am new to SNORT and can not figure out what the following rule means:

```
alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any-> $HOME_NET any (msg:"SCAN FIN"; flags: F;
reference:arachnids,27;
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like it would alert if it receives traffic from the defined external network ($EXTERNAL_NET) to your defined home network ($HOME_NET) where the TCP fin flag is set on it's own.

This could be taken to indicate a piece of scanning software, as in a standard TCP communication FIN isn't sent on it's own, it goes along with an ACK flack (there's more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination))